# how to send push notification via location through one signal plugin in wordpress(wordpress-admin)

Tags: wordpress, onesignal

I have no idea how to implement this plugin. 
My idea is, how to implement one signal plugin(in wordpress) could send push notification via location to my android studio app users. 
I want to group my app users via location so that only in that area can receive notification. 
Is there any best idea to configure onesignal plugin?

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Before posting, ***you are expected to have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself***. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

Please Read The api documentation for one signal post push notification.

first you need to create segment fro your backend of the one signal then use below code for send push notification.

```
<?PHP
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'Your Push notification message'
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "------------- Your App Id ----------",
        'included_segments' => array('Your Segment Name'),
  'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
print("\nJSON sent:\n");
print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);
print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
?>
```